# How to use a variable inside the ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the `ng-repeat` to list all the products, and I want to print out a star symbol `x` times depending on the `product.rating`. So, the code looks like following:

```
<p class="bs-rating"><i class="fa fa-star" ng-repeat="i in getRating({{ product.rating }}) track by $index"></i></p>
```

However, it parsed the `product.rating` as a `String`: `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/$parse/syntax?p0=product.rating&p1=is`

I have tried to remove the curly brackets, `{{ }}`:

```
<p class="bs-rating"><i class="fa fa-star" ng-repeat="i in getRating(product.rating) track by $index"></i></p>
```

It gave me `undefined`. My `getRating()` is declared as following:

```
$scope.getRating = function(rating){
    return new Array(parseInt(rating));
}
```

Could you help me figure it out how to pass a variable to `ng` tag?

Comment: Try putting `{{getRating(product.rating)}}` into the page and see what you get.  If that's undefined, there's a problem with your getRating() method.

Comment: Hey, your HTML is not valid, <p class="bs-rating"><i class="fa fa-star" ng-repeat="i in getRating(product.rating) track by $index"></i></p> pay attention to close <i

Comment: @SurrealDreams It still gave me the same error by parsing the entire `{{getRating(product.rating)}}` as String.

Comment: @Armen Thanks to point out but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on getRating function ie on generating the array.
I have developed an alternative solution on this link [rating using ng-repeat @jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YyBF/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        {{product.name}} 
        (
        <span style="font-weight:bold" ng-repeat="i in
           getRating(product.rating)">
            x
        </span>
        )
    </li>
</ol>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.products = [
        {name : "product1", rating:3},
        {name : "product2", rating:5},
        {name : "product3", rating:1}
        ];
    $scope.getRating = function(rating){
        var ratingArray = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= rating; i++) {
            ratingArray.push(i);
        }
        return ratingArray;
    };
});
```

Hopefully it will help.
Cheers